# Is it possible to avoid multiple button clicks on a Winform?

Tags: winforms, events, event-handling

Suppose you have a button on a form that counts to 1000 in a textbox and then clears it.

If I quickly click the button five times (in runtime) the Click event handler will be called 5 times and I will see the count to 1000 five times.

Is it possible to disable other clicks on that button while the first click is counting?

Note: Disabling the button in the first statement of the click handler and then re-enabling at the end does not work. Also, unsubscribing/subscribing to the click event (the -= followed by +=) does not work.

Here a sample to illustrate:

```
  private bool runningExclusiveProcess = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

        if (!runningExclusiveProcess)
        {
            runningExclusiveProcess = true;
            button1.Enabled = false;


            textBox1.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(i + Environment.NewLine);
            }


                runningExclusiveProcess = false;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
}
```

Comment: You're doing all the work on the UI thread. It will always reach the end of that method before allowing you to click the button again. The code probably takes a lot less time to run than you think.

Comment: Counting to 1000 isn't the delay it used to be.  Your computer is counting to 1000 between clicks.  (A few Sleep()s or other longer running function calls would show the behavior you're expecting)

Comment: @tzup You're right about the clicks being queued up even if the UI thread is blocked. I didn't know that. Will remove my answer :)

Comment: @Brad Bruce The idea is to avoid the event handler being called multiple times if the end-user quickly clicks it repeatedly. You can try putting the thread to sleep a couple of seconds to slow the function but it will still get executed as many times as you clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable button after initial click, run a timer for a second which will on tick reenable the button and disable itself

Answer (score 2):

Code snippet here:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Count = 0;
    }

    private void GOBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GOBtn.Enabled = false;

        this.Increment();

        this.GOBtn.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        this.Count++;
        this.CountTxtBox.Text = this.Count.ToString();
        this.CountTxtBox.Refresh();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);  //long process

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool HasBeenClicked = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if( HasBeenClicked )
          Application.DoEvents();
       else {
          HasBeenClicked = true;
          // Perform some actions here...
          }
    }
```

That oughta do it. :o)